# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized when trying to connect via web role

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to use web role example as shown in the following example, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues/. In step 9 I failed to continue due to unauthorized error. Can anybody point me what has gone wrong? Please see the images. Looks to me I have used the connection string properly. Thank you.

**Following image shows connection string from azure portal.**

[image]

**Following image shows how do I use the connection string.**

[image]

**Following image shows what I get when running the web role according to the tutorial.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider, you need to provide just the key and not the string you are providing.  The endpoint is already set 2 lines above when you create the uri.

Your connection string will look something like this:

```
Endpoint=<<endpoint>>/SharedAccessKey:<<key>>
```

Just put the key in.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I managed to make it working by the following statement:    return NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://m....servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=x.......=");  but could not make it working with my original way.

Comment: That string that you are entering is called the "connection string".  The key is one part of that string.  When creating the SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider, you need to only specify the key part (the area after the SharedAccessKey in the connection string) and not the entire connection string itself

Answer (score 0):

After trying in many different ways to get rid of the error, finally I found why it was giving me that error. This was because there was space before and after the equal sign. "Endpoint = sb://mahbu...  When I changed to "Endpoint=sb://mahbu...,  then the error disappeared.